# menu with text, graphic and separator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a c# / asp.net web site that needs a menu system.

I was looking at the intrinsic asp:menu, but it does not seem to account for these requirements....

Text that is over a graphic and a graphic to indicate a separator between each menu choices.

It also has to use a different color to denote the menu choice that is currently active.

This is a single level menu only - based on a master page design (menu is on master page), menu choices are on content pages.

Does anyone have a free tool that can accomplish this?

thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure the asp:menu can do this.  You can set image backgrounds on pretty much anything in winforms, there are (I believe) tools for separators, and you can control colors programmatically with the moveover events (if it isn't natively supported).

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361271/best-free-controls-for-net

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RadMenu telerik control`

LInk : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

You can also read this article :

[Best Free Controls for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361271/best-free-controls-for-net)

Comment: Isn't that control about $1,200?  pithhelmet asked for 'free' tools.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be accomplished by the .NET built-in menu.

Each ToolStripMenuItem has a BackgroundImage property (which can set a background graphic).  This class has a MouseHover event which you can capture to change the colors programmatically.

There's a [ToolStripSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripseparator.aspx) class which will let you add separators.

For a more detailed discussion of menus in .NET, see [this article](http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp/sdimdi/vcmi.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question.Still if somebody comes here again. This is for them :)

This is how I did it. Hope it helps someone...

**Method 1. By using images and code behind**

You will have a pair of images for each menu item. one for active and one for unselected

**aspx code**

```
                                <asp:Menu
            ID="Menu1"
            Width="1300px"
            runat="server"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
            OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick" >
            <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="mSelected" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="mSelected" />
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="images/selectedt1.jpg" Text="" Value="0" ></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="images/unselectedt2.jpg" Text="" Value="1"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="images/unselectedt3.jpg"  Text="" Value="2"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="images/unselectedt4.jpg"  Text="" Value="3"></asp:MenuItem>
  </Items>
  </asp:Menu>
```

**css**

```
 <style type="text/css">
.mSelected {border:none;border-collapse:collapse;border-width:0px;border-color:#ffffff;}  
</style>
```

**aspx.cs code**

```
     protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
        {

            int i = 0; // index of the menu item
   if (Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value) == 0)
            {
                Menu1.Items[0].ImageUrl = "images/selectedt1.jpg";
                Menu1.Items[1].ImageUrl = "images/unselectedt2.jpg";
                Menu1.Items[2].ImageUrl = "images/unselectedt3.jpg";
                Menu1.Items[3].ImageUrl = "images/unselectedt4.jpg";
            }
            if (Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value) == 1)
            {
                Menu1.Items[0].ImageUrl = "images/unselectedt1.jpg";
                Menu1.Items[1].ImageUrl = "images/selectedt2.jpg";
                Menu1.Items[2].ImageUrl = "images/unselectedt3.jpg";
                Menu1.Items[3].ImageUrl = "images/unselectedt4.jpg";
            }
            if (Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value) == 2)
            {
                Menu1.Items[0].ImageUrl = "images/unselectedt1.jpg";
                Menu1.Items[1].ImageUrl = "images/unselectedt2.jpg";
                Menu1.Items[2].ImageUrl = "images/selectedt3.jpg";
                Menu1.Items[3].ImageUrl = "images/unselectedt4.jpg";
            }
}
```

[Method 1 Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBUm1.png)

**Method 2. Using javascript and css**

**aspx code**

```
<asp:Menu
            ID="Menu1"
            runat="server"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
            OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick" DynamicSelectedStyle-ForeColor="Black" StaticMenuItemStyle-Height="22px" StaticMenuItemStyle-Width="120px" StaticMenuItemStyle-ItemSpacing="2px"  BackColor="#C3C3C3" Font-Size="16px" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="cambria" StaticMenuItemStyle-VerticalPadding="3px" StaticMenuStyle-Width="900px" StaticSelectedStyle-BackColor="White" StaticSelectedStyle-ForeColor="Black" StaticMenuItemStyle-BorderColor="White" StaticMenuItemStyle-BorderWidth="2px">
            <Items>

                <asp:MenuItem Text="Building" Value="0"></asp:MenuItem> 


                <asp:MenuItem Text="Allocation" Value="2" ></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Rent" Value="3" ></asp:MenuItem>

                <asp:MenuItem Text="Kahramaa" Value="4" ></asp:MenuItem>

                <asp:MenuItem Text="Owner" Value="5" ></asp:MenuItem>

                <asp:MenuItem Text="Type" Value="6" ></asp:MenuItem>

            </Items>

        </asp:Menu>
```

**javsacript code**

```
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script  type ="text/javascript">
         $(function () {   

             $("ul.level1 li").click(function () {             
                $(this).css("background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;");
             });
 });
</script>
```

[Method 2 result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV1DX.png)